# Sprite Kit - OS X - Window flashing on resize

Tags: macos, cocoa, sprite-kit, nswindow

OS X 10.9.3,  Xcode 5.1.1, MacBook 13",  NVIDIA GeForce 9400M 256 MB

If the following is performed in Xcode...

```
New -> Project -> OS X -> Sprite Kit Game
```

The resulting app features a single NSWindow, containing an SKView.

When run, the window appears, with the standard FPS counter and the ability to add Sprite Nodes (jet fighters) by clicking within the window.

**Problem:** resizing the window by dragging on a window edge causes the contents of the window to flash white. The flashing is variable, and seemingly dependent on the window edge being dragged, with the top and left edges producing the worst flashing.

**Question:** Apart from filing a bug, is there a way to fix this or bypass it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have the same issue with an SKView in a NSScrollView, when scrolling the SKView is constantly flicker.

Comment: I had this issue and just disabled resizing the window.

Comment: @Okapi, alas that is not a viable solution for my app. Customers have very different sized screens...